# Autocommand to execute just once after a many files save ( :wa )

Tags: vim

I have autocmd for BufWritePost in my plugin. (i update tags for a whole project in this autocommand, this is plugin Indexer.tar.gz )

Sometimes i need to save many files (i do ":wa" ). And, of course, my autocmd is called for each filesave.

I'd like to make it call just after ALL filesaves. Say, if i have 20 unsaved buffers, i do :wa, and my autocmd is called just once, after the last buffer is saved.
Is there any way to do it?

Actually this plugin is smart enough, it starts ctags in background if possible, but anyway this is a bit annoying.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do with the autocmd? In general?

Comment: @ldigas, I already wrote: i update tags for a whole project in this autocommand, this is plugin Indexer.tar.gz . When user saves file, my plugin executes ctags for a whole project, to make tags always up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

One way without autocommand:

```
function! MyFunction()
    "" Save all buffers.
    bufdo wa  
    "" Run your command once.
    ... your command ... 
endfunction

nnoremap ,wa :call MyFunction()<CR>
```

Push `,wa` in normal mode (without colon) and all your buffers will be saved and later it will run your command.

**EDIT**: Modify function to return to previous buffer, because `bufdo` changes it:

```
function! MyFunction()
    "" Save number of current buffer.
    let l:current_buffer = bufnr("%")

    "" Save all buffers.
    bufdo wa  

    "" Bufdo probably changed the buffer, so return to where we were before running previous command.
    execute "buffer " . l:current_buffer

    "" Run your command once.
    ... your command ... 
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking for the solution to make standard :wa work, to make it easier to use by other users of my plugin. Actually this is a variant to use plugin cmdalias ( http://goo.gl/8W6VD ) and override :wa command , but it seems to be too tricky. Looking for more natural way.

Answer (score 0):

There is this [CursorHold](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CursorHold) event, that is triggered *"when the user doesn't press a key for the time specified with 'updatetime'"* (which defaults to 4 sec). This event will be triggered `updatetime` miliseconds after saving the files unless the user keeps typing. A `BufWrite` autocommand can temporarily make this settimg very low, say 50ms and add a self-disabling autocommand for `CursorHold`. The `BufWrite` autocommand can check if it already configured the `CursorHold` handler this time around to avoid adding it multiple times.

To make it somewhat flexible I make this construct fire custom ([User](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#User)) events: when the first save is detected, then for each file in the "save batch" and finally when the timeout fires. This way my other scripts can handle any of these events independently.

Implementation:

```
function! s:WriteTimeoutSchedule()
  if !exists("#WriteTimeout#CursorHold")
    let s:oldUpdateTime = &ut
    set updatetime=50
    augroup WriteTimeout
      au CursorHold * call s:WriteTimeoutFire()
    augroup END
    do User WriteTimeoutPre
  endif
  do User WriteTimeoutEach
endfunction

function! s:WriteTimeoutFire()
  do User WriteTimeoutPost
  au! WriteTimeout
  let &ut=s:oldUpdateTime
endfunction

aug WriteTimeoutSupport
  au!
  au BufWrite * call s:WriteTimeoutSchedule()
aug END
```

Usage example: [toucher.vim](https://github.com/gastropoda/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/config/toucher.vim).